# Is it safe to use `expo install` for everything that I need to install?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm working on an expo project. We have to use `expo install` when adding other expo libraries (e.g. `expo-permissions`, `expo-av`). But we can also use `expo install` for non-expo libraries (e.g. `react-native-root-toast`). So, is it safe to use `expo install` for all libraries that we install?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with using it to install all of your dependencies. All expo install does is check for compatibilities with your current expo version.

From expo docs:

> The expo install command will pick a version that is compatible with your project and then use your JavaScript package manager (such as npm) to install it.

So if you use yarn instead of npm for example, expo will use yarn instead.

Comment: So if I install with a normal `npm install <package>` is the version just not guaranteed to work with expo?