# calling a stack function in a tab navigator causes app to crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have noticed that in my App.js, when I call my function MyTabs(which holds a stack navigator) in my tab navigator it causes the app to crash on IOS when run locally.

When the app does crash, I noticed zero errors are logged. I do not get errors in my terminal or on the screen. I am running it through npm start along with the expo app on my personal device. I have tried other devices as well but still the same crash. I also do not have a mac, I bet using xCode could atleast give me an error.

I have included a snack demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/appjs-crashing) as well as a git repository including every file in the project [here](https://github.com/priedejm/stackoverflow).

Any insight at all would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:: I am assuming since it works on snack it must be my environment. I have tried an entirely different computer and device but I have always started it using npm start and the expo app.

EDIT 2:: I noticed I do get this warning. Could something like this cause it to crash?[image]

Here is the app.js

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (

    <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Home">        
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>

);
}

export default function App() {

  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#F60081',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
        
      },
      
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={MyTabs}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Comment: what if you move line `const Stack = createStackNavigator();`  to the top of your code. I mean before calling it. some where like before or after line `const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();`

Comment: unfortunately nothing

Comment: Then use flipper to see the crash log

Comment: Also, you shouldn't push `./node_modules` to a remote repository like GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your **Edit 2** try this

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens
```

then as [the link says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63788380/7178860) install the packages with `expo install` command again to be sure that you have the compatible versions in your expo project

Comment: Thank you. Expo install will be what I continue to do from hear on out.

Comment: you're welcome dude

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

[image]

I was getting this error:

> Cannot find module
> '/stackoverflow/node_modules/vlq/dist/vlq.js'.
> Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

After installing a package, I was getting same error for a different packages. Looks like packages could not communicate each other

Comment: Interesting, I have tried this but no luck. I just get the iOS Bundling Complete but no iOs running app on iphone. Would it be too much to ask of you to upload your node_modules somewhere? I think it could help troubleshoot if I was able to have one that I know worked.

Comment: @JustinPriede I did not install anything new. To be sure delete your .expo folder too. so, delete .expo, node_modules, package-lock.json and run npm install

Comment: So weird, still just crashes with zero errors logged.

Comment: @JustinPriede try this ` react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: @JustinPriede expo --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
4.13.0 and node --version 
v14.17.3

Comment: still no luck. Current versions are expo 5.0.3 and node v14.18.1

I appreciate your time

Comment: @JustinPriede it is definitely config issue. Build a new project and then install the needed dependencies and just copy the components.

Comment: I have tried this actually multiple times, I will look to move to another environment. Thanks for the help!